# Complex toggle behaviour with angular.js

Tags: angularjs

**Situation:**

I work with angular.js for frontend (newbie) and with symfony2 (php) for backend. I query for a list of users and groups. So the html could look like that.

```
<ul class="user-list">
    <li ng-repeat="user in users">
        <a ng:click="select(user)">
              {{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="user-was-selected" ng-show="selectedUser != null">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="group in groups"><a>{{ group.name }}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When a user is selected from the list another view will be shown that displays a dropdown list filled with groups. This are all groups available. So the list query does not depend on the user.

However a user can be a member of a group. So I need to set a class on the li element, like "in-group".

In symfony2 this is easy, because its templating engine "twig" has methods like user.hasGroup to check if the user is in the group. I can do this right in the twig template.

**My question** is, do I have to make a rest api call for this? It would mean I have to make a rest api group check per group for every user. Does this make any sense or do you see another solution?

In addition to that, a click on a group from the dropdown would remove/add (toggle) the user from the clicked group.

Comment: You can use ng-class to conditionally apply a class. The condition would be something like "selectedUser.hasGroup". If you don't have that method, add it to your User resource prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would add `ng-class` to your `li`

```
<ul class="user-list">
    <li ng-repeat="user in users">
        <a ng:click="select(user)">
              {{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="user-was-selected" ng-show="selectedUser != null">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-class="{in-group: selectedUser.inGroup}" ng-repeat="group in groups"><a>{{ group.name }}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You would add the `inGroup` method to your `User` resource like this (assuming you have a factory):

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('User', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  var User = $resource(...);

  ...

  User.prototype.inGroup = function(group) {
    //determine if user is in group
    //'this' (selectedUser) and 'group' are at your disposal
    //return true if there's a match
  };

  ...

  return User;
}]);
```